# Send file via IdTCPServer upon request of client

Tags: delphi-7, tcpclient, indy, tcpserver

I am trying to send a text-file via the TCP-server if a client request is performed. The examples on internet are either outdated or not useful. I know I should use a stream but I do not understand how to do it.

I adapted a code I found on the internet but I am stuck with regards to the stream. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

#### The server:

```
TForm2.bStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not IdTCPServer1.Active then
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
    Log('Server started on port ' + IntToStr(IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort));
    bStart.Enabled := False;
    bStop.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.bStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IdTCPServer1.Active then
  begin
    IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
    Log('Server stopped');
    bStop.Enabled := False;
    bStart.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bStart.Enabled := True;
  bStop.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;   FS:TFileStream;
begin

  if s ='1' then
  begin
    FS := TFileStream.Create(MyPath, fmOpenShare);
    try
      AContext.Connection.WriteStream(FS);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.Log(const s: string);
begin
  mLog.Lines.Add(s);
end
```

#### The client:

```
procedure TForm1.bConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Host := eServer.Text;
  IdTCPClient1.Port := StrToInt(ePort.Text);
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;

  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then
  begin
    Log('Connected to ' + IdTCPClient1.Host + ':' +
      IntToStr(IdTCPClient1.Port));
    bConnect.Enabled := False;
    bDisconnect.Enabled := True;
    bSend.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.bDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  bDisconnect.Enabled := False;
  bConnect.Enabled := True;
  bSend.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.bSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
//  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(eTextToSend.Text);

  FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    IdTCPClient1.ReadStream(FS);
  finally
    Fs.Free;
  end;


end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bDisconnect.Enabled := False;
  bSend.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(const s: string);
begin
  mLog.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is not sending any command to the server, and the server is not waiting for any command before sending a file.

But, besides that, your code doesn't compile anyway, as `TIdTCPConnection` does not have `WriteStream()` and `ReadStream()` methods.  The correct methods are `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()`.

But even then, your calls to write a stream and read a stream are mismatched, because `Write(TStream)` does not send the stream size to the peer by default, but `ReadStream()` does expect to receive a stream size by default.

Try something more like this instead:

#### The server:

```
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  if s = 'SENDFILE' then
  begin
    try
      FS := TFileStream.Create(MyPath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    except
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('500 Cannot open file');
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('200 Sending file');
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(FS, 0, True);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
  end
  else    
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('500 Unknown command');
end;
```

#### The client:

```
procedure TForm1.bSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.SendCmd('SENDFILE', 200);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, -1, False);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.txt');
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

In which case, you might consider using `TIdCmdTCPServer` instead, then you can use its `CommandHandlers` collection to define your commands visually at design-time, and assign `OnCommand` event handlers to process them at runtime, eg:

```
// OnCommand handler for 'SENDFILE' command
procedure TForm2.IdCmdTCPServer1SENDFILECommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    FS := TFileStream.Create(MyPath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  except
    ASender.SetReply(500, 'Cannot open file');
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    ASender.SetReply(200, 'Sending file');
    ASender.SendReply;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(FS, 0, True);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```